# How get unmatched list from dictionary

Tags: c#, linq

I want to get unmatched dictionary based on list item using LINQ. Please refer my sample code

```
Dictionary<string, List<int>> lowerActionRoles = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();
Dictionary<string, List<int>> upperActionRoles = new Dictionary<string, List<int>>();

lowerActionRoles.Add("11", new List<int>() { 1, 2, 4 });
upperActionRoles.Add("11", new List<int>() { 1, 2, 4, 5 });
lowerActionRoles.Add("13", new List<int>() { 1, 2, 4 });

lowerActionRoles.Add("21", new List<int>() { 1, 2, 4 });
upperActionRoles.Add("21", new List<int>() { 1, 2, 4 });
```

Here I have 2 dictionary lowerActionRoles and upperActionRoles. Dictionary with key 21 matched and key 11 is not matched. Here I want get dictionary with key 11.

Comment: What kind of output are you looking for?

Comment: I looking mismatched dictionary like below, but based on list item with key.  var unmatchActionRoles1 = (from v1 in lowerActionRoles
                                              from v2 in upperActionRoles
                                              where v1.Key == v2.Key && v2.Value.IsIn(v1.Value)
                                              select new { v1.Key, value1 = v1.Value, value2 = v2.Value }).ToList();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test if there is key present in both of dictionaries by using `ContainsKey` and then for checking values of that list by using `SequenceEqual` like

```
var result = upperActionRoles
             .Where(entry => lowerActionRoles.ContainsKey(entry.Key) && !lowerActionRoles[entry.Key].SequenceEqual(entry.Value))
             .ToDictionary(entry => entry.Key, entry => entry.Value);
```

And to display your result on the console window,

```
foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key: " + item.Key);
    Console.WriteLine();
    item.Value.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine("Value: " + x));
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:** If you want to get a list from another dictionary then just switch the dictionaries name on above query.

Comment: Thank you so much Guys for helping. It is working for me. I modified your concept for my suitable result as below var pairedUnMatched = (from v1 in unmatchedList
                                   join v2 in upperActionRoles
                                   on v1.Key equals v2.Key
                                   select new { v1.Key, value1 = v1.Value, value2 = v2.Value }).ToList();

Answer (score 1):

Based on the assumption that items in only one of the dictionaries should be ignored:

```
lowerActionRoles.Where(entry =>
{
    if (upperActionRoles.TryGet(entry.Key, out List<int> upperActionList))
    {
        return !upperActionList.SequenceEqual(entry.Value);
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This will return you a collection of entries in `lowerActionRoles` (`IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, List<int>>>`).

If you're interested only in the keys, add

```
.Select(entry => entry.Key);
```

to the previous query

and to convert to a new dictionary:

```
.ToDictionary(entry => entry.Key, entry => entry.Value);
```

Comment: Great it works for me. but it is return only one dictionary lowerActionRoles. I want both dictionary. Like  var unmatchActionRoles = (from v1 in upperActionRoles
                                              join v2 in lowerActionRoles
                                              on v1.Key equals v2.Key
                                              select new { v1.Key, Value1 = v1.Value, Value2 = v2.Value }).ToList();     Do i need write join with above result?

Comment: Since you seem to be only interested in entries that have keys in both dictionaries, why do you need to add anything?

Comment: hi, vc 74, your code is correct. I was just interested in unmatched list values for matched key. Thank You